# Flutter - Change the status bar color & it always show at the top

Tags: flutter, flutter-android

I'm a newbie in Flutter. I change the status bar color with code:

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarColor: Colors.green,
));
```

and this is result:

[image: image-1]

UI when dialog is showing:

[image: image-2]

When the dialog appears, I see the status bar is still visible at the top, it's not under the overlay, the UI looks ugly. I want when the dialog appears, the overlay is on top of the status bar as well. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can set status bar color transparent, so you can control the color with your widget, which behind the status bar.

If you want to control status icon/text color(white/black), you can do it this way:

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark);// or SystemUiOverlayStyle.white
```

Comment: I just wanted to colorize the status bar once, and I did it with code ```SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle```. But when the dialog appears, the dialog's overlay is not on the status bar so the UI looks bad.